# pyopencl errror : undefined symbol: clCreateSubDevices

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, x86-64, pyopencl, ubuntu-13.10

I have installed pyopencl. When I try :

```
 python /home/a/pyopencl/examples/benchmark.py
```

then I have an error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/a/pyopencl/examples/benchmark.py", line 6, in <module>
 import pyopencl as cl
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl-2013.3-py2.7-linux-   
 x86_64.egg/pyopencl/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
 import pyopencl._cl as _cl
 ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl-2013.3-py2.7-linux-     
 x86_64.egg/pyopencl/_cl.so: undefined symbol: clCreateSubDevices
```

How can I solve it ?

TIA

```
 Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
 [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
 Linux zalman 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64   
 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 4.304.88   Driver Version: 304.88         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     | Bus-Id        Disp.  | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 770          | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 25%   29C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |   7%  149MB / 2047MB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
 ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors
 nvidia.icd



 locate libOpenCL.so


 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_libOpenCL.so
 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_libOpenCL.so_lib32
 /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so
 /usr/lib32/libOpenCL.so

  nvcc --version
  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
  Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
  Built on Fri_Sep_21_17:28:58_PDT_2012
  Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
```

Answer (score 2):

clCreateSubDevices was introduced in OCL 1.2. Last time I've check NVIDIA was still not supporting OCL 1.2. Maybe it changed lately... better check.

You can use the `class pyopencl.Device` to query which version of OCL is available to you. Documentation [here](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html#platforms-devices-and-contexts).

Answer (score 1):

found this solution posted by the pyopencl man himself:

> Solution: Add
>
> CL_PRETEND_VERSION = "1.1"
>
> to siteconf.py.
>
> Problem: If you feed PyOpenCL headers for CL 1.2 and then compile
>   against an ICD loader that doesn't implement 1.2 functions (e.g.
>   clCreateSubDevice), then you get this breakage. The above fixes that,
>   by forcing PyOpenCL to ignore 1.2.
>
> Andreas

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.opencl/1328

But now I've got another error as well:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytools-2014.3.5-py2.7.egg/pytools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from six.moves import range, zip, intern, input
ImportError: cannot import name intern
```

Comment: If someone stumbles upon this and also wonders where to find siteconf.py. You have to get the pyopencl source (clone [pyopencl](https://github.com/pyopencl/pyopencl) from github), then run `python configure.py` in the repository and a `siteconf.py` will be created. After editing it you can run `pip install .` to install it. The `ImportError` is due to an outdated version of six, and can be fixed simply by updating it `pip install --upgrade six`.